# Get a red line under Any at = IsAvailable = !b.BorrowHistories.Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello I got this error.

'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Get a red line under Any at = IsAvailable = !b.BorrowHistories.Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LibraryManagement.Models;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;

namespace LibraryManagement.Controllers
{
    public class BooksController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Books
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var books = db.Books.Include(h => h.BorrowHistories)
                .Select(b => new BookViewModel
                {
                    BookId = b.BookId,
                    Author = b.Author,
                    Publisher = b.Publisher,
                    SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber,
                    Title = b.Title,
                    IsAvailable = !b.BorrowHistories.Any(h => h.ReturnDate == null)
                }).ToList();
            return View(books);
        }
```

Im following a tutorial on how to create a Libary management system with Asp.net MVC.

Thanks

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Any` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, which `ICollection` does not implement (but `ICollection<T>` does). If you can get an `ICollection<T>` you could use it; otherwise, you can write your own efficient `Any` (works the same way as the .NET version, with a performance tweak .NET Framework doesn't have but .NET Core does):

Note: the snippet below uses older C# language version since it's unknown what the baseline is.

```cs
public class Extensions
{
  public static bool Any(this IEnumerable source)
  {
    if (source == null) throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    // Performance tweak to eliminate allocation of enumerator if we have a count.
    if (source is ICollection) return ((ICollection)source).Count > 0;

    IEnumerator e = source.GetEnumerator();
    bool any = e.MoveNext();

    // Make sure the enumerator is properly disposed of if necessary.
    // IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable but an implementation of IEnumerator itself might.
    if (e is IDisposable) ((IDisposable)e).Dispose();
    return any;
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed public ICollection BorrowHistories { get; set; } in my BooksController to public ICollection<BorrowHistory> BorrowHistories { get; set; } and this did the trick like you suggested.